# Is it possible to use a skeleton example as a pending in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to use a skeleton(empty) example as a pending. Normally, it is treated as succeeded(Green), but this occurs misunderstandings, like this.

```
describe "" do
  # This is displayed as **not pending** but succeeded. 
  it "A skeleton example 1." do
  end

  # If you want to display result as a pending,
  # need to implement the procedure explicitly.
  it "A skeleton example 2." do
    skip "Not Implemented."
  end
end
```

To writing `skip ...` each time is very painful... So I avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To flag example as pending - just remove `do..end` block.

```
it 'is not pending example' do
end

it 'is pending example'
```

Comment: eeeeeexcellent! Thank you for very much. Rspec is very nice. I will accept this answer afterward(In stackoverflow, accepting within 10 minutes is prohibited...)